# What does 'sizeof (function name)' return?

Tags: c, function, sizeof

Sample code:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf ("size = %d\n", sizeof(main));
}
```

What is the returned value `sizeof` applied to a function name, for example `main`?

Comment: My guess is that the -1 was because of TIAS ("try it and see").

Comment: The problem with TIAS is that it usually doesn't work, because all you see is what _your current compiler with your current options_ actually does, which could be quite different from what a compiler is _supposed to do_. Something that's just been proven another time with the discussions found below. (You actually have to add a `-pedantic` option to GCC's command line to observe the "official" behavior. And that's just one compiler) So here's a +1 from me just to counter the stupid TIAS down-vote.

Answer (score 20):

C standard forbids it - when compiled with `gcc -pedantic`, it produces `invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to a function type` warning.

However `gcc` compiles it and returns `1` for `sizeof(main)`, and it is not a size of function pointer.

It seems to be compiler-dependent.

Comment: While `gcc` may compile it, it is not clear that it is performing the translation from `main` to `&main`.  For example, codepad--which uses gcc 4.1.2--returns a size of 1 for `sizeof(main)` but a size of 4 for `sizeof(&main)`.

Comment: @Aeth You are completely correct, I got the same result with latest and greatest GCC 4.5. Post edited.

Answer (score 9):

> #### [The sizeof Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w557fh7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
>
> ```
>  sizeof unary-expression
>  sizeof ( type-name )
> ```
>
> The operand is either an identifier that is a unary-expression, or a type-cast expression (that is, a type specifier enclosed in parentheses). **The unary-expression cannot represent a bit-field object, an incomplete type, or a `function designator`**. The result is an unsigned integral constant. The standard header STDDEF.H defines this type as `size_t`.

Use compilation flag `-Wall -pedantic` to emit warning about incorrect operand to `sizeof` (remember `sizeof` is a compilation time operator), Code:

```
$ cat sizeof.c 
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(){
    printf("%zu %p\n", sizeof(main), (void*)main);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation message with GCC version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5):

```
$ gcc -Wall -pedantic sizeof.c -std=c99
sizeof.c: In function ‘main’:
sizeof.c:3:30: warning: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to a function type 
              [-pedantic]
sizeof.c:3:38: warning: ISO C forbids conversion of function pointer to 
              object pointer type [-pedantic]
```

Read also:

> #### [6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.4.html)
>
> 1118 — The `sizeof` operator shall *not* be applied to an expression that has function type or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field member
>   1127 — The value of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (an unsigned integer type) is `size_t`, defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers)

Additionally, correct format string for `size_t` is `%zu` and If it doesn't exists for example Microsoft's compiler then you can use `%lu` and convert the returned value to `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 7):

ISO C++ forbids applying `sizeof` to an expression of function type.

ISO/IEC 14882 on C++ says (section 5.3.3):

*"The size operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function or incomplete type,..."*

The same hold for standard C (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) section 6.5.3.4:

"*The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field member."*

Comment: What is the rational behind it?

Comment: This question is tagged as C, so the C++ standard has no bearing.

Comment: @Aeth many parts of the C++ standard are adopted from C. See the updated answer with added reference.

Comment: @yassin: Probably that `sizeof` is only meaningful for objects, which have a representation as `unsigned char [sizeof(type)]`. In C, functions do not have representations (there is no conversion from function pointer types to data pointer types) so there's no meaningful use for `sizeof`.

Answer (score 3):

As per ISO C11 section `6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators`, sub-section 1 (constraints):

> The `sizeof` operator ***shall not*** be applied to an expression that has function type or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field member.

There's also a subsection 4 in section `6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators` which states:

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator<sup>(65)</sup> or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type "function returning
>   type" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning
>   type"".

Foot note 65, referenced from there, clarifies the point:

> Because this conversion does not occur, the operand of the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator remains a function designator and violates the constraints in 6.5.3.4.

As per section `4 Conformance`:

> In this International Standard, "shall" is to be interpreted as a requirement on an implementation or on a program; conversely, "shall not" is to be interpreted as a ***prohibition.***

Hence a strictly conforming program should never take the size of a function. But, then again, it probably should also use a correct form of `main()` :-)

There is a loophole here, however. A conforming implementation is allowed to provide extensions "provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly
conforming program" (section `4 Conformance`, subsection `6`).

You could argue that this *is* a behavioural change (allowing `sizeof(function)` rather than disallowing it) but, since the original program wouldn't have been strictly conforming in the first place, the subsection does not forbid it.

Comment: Conforming implementations may offer extensions so long as they report diagnostics where required, and the extension does not alter the behaviour of any conforming program

Comment: if my memory is correct, `gcc` is defined to return `1`. correct me if my brain is in jam again.

Comment: @Matt, good point, I originally saw this as a behavioural change hence disallowed. But, since the change would have been made to a *non* strictly conforming program, it's irrelevant. Updated the answer to adjust.