# Understanding function pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

```
int f1(){}
int* f2(){}

int main()
{
    int *a;//1
    int b;
    int *c;
    a=c; 
    a=&b; 

    int (*p)(); //2
    p=f2; //showing error
    p=&f1;
}
```

I expected that in my program '2' must behave similar to '1'. Why function pointer are behaving differently. Or am I missing something?

Comment: `f2` is a function returning a pointer to `int` (and would be converted into an `int * (*)()` in the line `p = f2;` if it compiled). `p` is a pointer to a function returning `int`. Incompatible types.

Comment: Here's a tip to help declare function pointer types easily: `typedef int type_of_f1();`. Now just add a star and you have `type_of_f1* p;` to declare a function pointer suitable for f1.

Comment: A good [book](www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do all these crazy function pointer definitions all work? What is really going on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-all-these-crazy-function-pointer-definitions-all-work-what-is-really-goi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p=f2;` error because incompatible types. `f2` is a function that can return a `int*` whereas `p` is pointer to function that can point to a function  returns `int` e.g. `f1()`

for `int* f2()`, you can defined a pointer to function  as below:

```
 int* (*p2)();   // pointers to function f2
 p2 = f2;
```

Additionally, you don't need to use `&` before function name just function name is enough. 
Here is a good link to read: [Why do all these crazy function pointer definitions all work? What is really going on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-all-these-crazy-function-pointer-definitions-all-work-what-is-really-goi?lq=1)

**Edit**:
Some time `&functionname` and `functionname` are not same e.g. [`sizeof(functionname)` is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666392/what-does-sizeof-function-name-return/14909202#14909202) whereas `sizeof(&functionname)` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks. But why p2=f2;? why not p2=&f2;

Comment: @Alex, those two forms are interchangeable when it comes to functions.

Comment: @Alex You can try `p=*******************************************f2;`

Comment: @Alex you don't need `&` for function address, just function name is enough (but you can & it not wrong), there is good link wait

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure, but I heard that `*f2` is equals to `f2`. ( Only if `f2` is a pointer function )

Comment: @Alex and `&f2` is equal to `f2` :) in function, read: [Function pointers and address of a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552663/function-pointers-and-address-of-a-function)

Comment: @G But you can't do `p=&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&f2` nor `p=& & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &f2`

Comment: @Alex ok read this: [Why do all these crazy function pointer definitions all work? What is really going on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-all-these-crazy-function-pointer-definitions-all-work-what-is-really-goi?lq=1)

Comment: @Alex [this link](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/function.html) may also be helpful some time because you also added c++ tag.

Answer (score 3):

```
int* f2(){}
```

A function that accepts nothing, and returns **a pointer to an int**.

```
int (*p)();
```

A pointer to: A function that accepts nothing and returns an **int**

You have a type mismatch. `p` is not a pointer to the type of `f2`

If you have trouble understanding such definitions, like all mortal do, use the [spiral rule of thumb](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is a function that returns `int*`

```
int* f2(){}
```

So you need:

```
(int*) (*q)();
q = f2;
```

Answer (score 1):

`p` is pointer to function taking void argument and returning integer.

`f1` is a function taking void argument and returning integer.

`f2` is a function taking void argument and returning pointer to integer.

Now as per definitions you can see `f1` can be assigned to `p` but `f2` can't.To assign `f2` in `p`, declaration of `p` should be `int *(*p)();`

Answer (score 1):

You have made wrong assignments i.e incompatible types

For the functions

```
int f1(){}
int* f2(){}
```

The correct assignments would be

```
int (*p)(); 
p = f1;

int* (*p)();
p = f2;
```