# Defining function pointer in C?

Tags: c, typedef, function-declaration

1. Recently I came across a surprising way of defining a function pointer in C:

```
typedef void (func_type)(void);
func_type *func_ptr;
```

Is this a correct way of defining a function pointer?

2. If we define func_obj as below, what is the type of this object and what this object can be used for?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (func_type)(void);
func_type *func_ptr;

func_type func_obj;

int main()
{
  printf("Size of func_obj: %zu\n", sizeof func_obj);
  printf("Size of func_ptr: %zu\n", sizeof func_ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

The code prints:

```
Size of func_obj: 1
Size of func_ptr: 8
```

Comment: Does this answer (some of) your questions? [What does 'sizeof (function name)' return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666392/what-does-sizeof-function-name-return)

Comment: Yes, both object types (including function pointer types) and function types can be typedefed as standard. Applying the `sizeof` operator to a function type is a constraint violation.

Comment: typedefing a function type can be useful to save typing (and ease maintainability) if you want to forward declare a whole bunch of functions with the same prototype, say for a lookup table.

Comment: It is perfectly valid since the dawn of C. In C23, one can even do `typeof(void(void))* func_ptr;`.

Comment: Inasmuch as C draws a firm distinction between functions and objects, the identifier `func_obj` in this example is misleading.  It identifies a function, not an object, notwithstanding that its (function) type is conveyed via a `typedef`ed type name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These declarations

```
typedef void (func_type)(void);
func_type *func_ptr;
```

are similar to declarations like for example

```
typedef int T;
T *int_ptr;
```

So there is nothing wrong with the typedef that intrduces an alias for a function type.

Pay attention to that this typedef declaration

```
typedef void (func_type)(void);
```

is equivalent to

```
typedef void func_type(void);
```

This declaration

```
func_type func_obj;
```

declares a function with the name `func_obj` of the type `void( void )`.

Such a declaration allows for example to list functions in one line without repeating their parameter lists.

This statement

```
printf("Size of func_obj: %zu\n", sizeof func_obj);
```

is invalid according to the C Standard because you may not apply the `sizeof` operator to a functon.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 1 **The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
> function type** or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such
> a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field member. The
> alignof operator shall not be applied to a function type or an
> incomplete type.

Some compilers however can have their own extensions that contradict the C Standard.

Comment: It is intriguing that GCC returns a size of 1. That doesn't make much sense, it should throw an error instead. I wonder what the rationales are.

Comment: @Elzaidir https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you, very interesting. It makes sense that this is needed for pointer arithmetic of functions and void types.

Comment: @KamilCuk That's not a rationale. That's "developer x was bored and invented a new GNU C feature just for the heck of it". I still can't see any reason why you would ever want to do pointer arithmetic on void pointers or function pointers - the need for doing so originates from confused program design.

Answer (score 2):

> s this a correct way of defining a function pointer?

Yes.

I prefer to define a function type and then use `*` with it. It is immediately visible that `func_type *` is a pointer, vs `typedef void (*func_type)(void); func_type func;` hides that information.

> func_obj as below, what type if this object of?

`func_obj` is literally a *function*. Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void func_type(void);
// forward declaration of a function
void func_obj(void);
// typedef is just an alias, exactly the same as above
func_type func_obj;
// for function definition, we have to use a ()
void func_obj(void) {
    printf("Inside func_obj\n");
}
int main() {
     func_obj();
}
```

Doing `sizeof(func_obj)` is technically invalid - [What does 'sizeof (function name)' return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666392/what-does-sizeof-function-name-return) .

> what this object can be used for?

Well, like a function, for calling it. Alias can be used for keeping function types in sync.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a correct way of defining a function pointer?

Yes. There are two different coding styles:

- Either `typedef` a function and declare an object as a pointer to that function:;

  ```c
  typedef void func_t (void);
  ...
  func_t* fptr;
  ```
- Or hide the pointer inside the `typedef`:

  ```c
  typedef void (*func_t) (void);
  ...
  func_t fptr;
  ```

Which one to use is mostly a matter of preference.

The former makes function pointers behave as object pointers do, so it is nice for consistency and what I would personally recommend. It is generally a bad idea to hide pointers inside a `typedef`. Good code should be self-documenting.

The latter is historically the most common and you are expected to understand it as well. I used it too for a long while before I converted to the former style.

---

> If we define func_obj as below, what is the type of this object and what this object can be used for?

It declares a function type. It is another dangerous GNU C thing - you *cannot* apply `sizeof` on a function in conforming C (see constraints 6.5.3.4). gcc and clang are clearly non-conforming here unless you add `-pedantic`.

As for what the purpose of this "feature" is... as with any other such mildly useful GNU C feature: implemented for the sake of implementing new features. I can't find any rationale or explanation anywhere for what this "feature" would actually be good for. What it is *bad* for is quite obvious: it reduces type safety of the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: As stated by @KamilCuk the rational behind `sizeof` function being 1 is explained [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html). In short, this is a side effect of allowing arithmetic operations on function pointers. Now why are arithmetic operations allowed on function pointers is a different topic.

Comment: @Elzaidir That's not a rationale, it's like saying "we replaced the wheel in the car with a kitchen sink in order to make it possible to drive cars using kitchen sinks".